# issue while importing excel to sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I have faced strange problem in SQL Server while importing data from Excel. The Excel file which I import was exported from Crystal Reports.

I used this query

```
SELECT 
   *, '10000143' as bank  
FROM 
   OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
              'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\\xampplite\htdocs\EXCEL\data\kbl.xls;IMEX=1',
              'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

I created separate new Excel file (using Microsoft Office) and saved it as `.xls` (2003 compatible). I tried to import this excel using above query but it throws error.

> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>   Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)".

Again I created one html file as below

```
<table>
<tr>
   <td>r1<td>
   <td>r2<td>
   <td>r3<td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>1<td>
   <td>2<td>
   <td>3<td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I exported above html file to excel via internet explorer. Then I tried to import it to SQL Server using query above. It worked like a charm.

I have no idea how to import an Excel file which is created using Microsoft Office?

Comment: Which version of operating system do you have? 32bit or 64bit?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your query has an extra backslash

```
Excel 8.0;Database=C:\\xampplite\htdocs\EXCEL\data\kbl.xls;IMEX=1'
```

User

```
  Excel 8.0;Database=C:\xampplite\htdocs\EXCEL\data\kbl.xls;IMEX=1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard?

Right click a database node in Object `Explorer --> Tasks --> Import Data...`

The wizard can then be used to import the Excel file as desired, giving you control over which columns and what datatypes you want to import.

The wizard will then generate and run an `SSIS package`, which you have the option of saving too.

I wouldn't have mentioned it, but you stated

```
" have no idea how to import an Excel file which is created using Microsoft Office?"
```

Suggesting `OPENROWSET` was the only method you were aware of.